# Maas will commission machine, but won't let me turn it on

Tags: juju, maas

I have an extant maas/juju system that I can build from scratch with scripts, and do fairly regularly, these are Dell C6015 systems.  I just got 6 more machines - HP DL580 G7s.  I rebuilt the cluster from scratch, and MAAS sees the new machines, and can commission them.  They show the correct number of cores, memory and disk, and show "ready".  The original Dell systems come on line and work just fine, and are allocated to, and provisioned by, juju.

I tried allocating them in juju, MAAS started them, allocated them, marked them deploying, and then deployed, but in juju they never showed as other then pending.

I remove-machined them in juju, but they were not released, so I forced them and released them in MAAS.  I tried to debug their hooks, to see what was going on, and I tried reallocating them in juju, even using add-machine and add unit --to, but they never were allocated again.  I was able to turn them on and off from MAAS for a while (this stopped).  I can still allocate, deploy and release them, get MAAS to commission them again and check their power status.

What MAAS won't do is let me turn them on.  MAAS will let me re-commission them, and it cycles through, turning them on, running the scripts and shutting them down, as often as I want.  I can acquire, deploy them and release them, through MAAS.

But when I select any one or more to turn on, MAAS says "1 node cannot be powered on. To proceed, update your selection."

I can power them on using their iLO (IPMI) web interface, and when I do, I can shut them off with MAAS.  But, no joy on starting any of them through maas, or getting juju to put services on them.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be the issue, what I can do to debug the problem, or want me to add log info from MAAS or juju?  All help would be very appreciated.

If I can get them going, I can hack through running the juju service scripts by hand, so i can use the cores.  But no power cycle, no joy.

```
2015.12.18 Edit -----------------------
```

My current work around is to deploy them by hand:

In maas,

```
select the systems in question, select "Take Action"/“Acquire” and “Go”
select the systems in question, "Take Action"/“Deploy” and “Go”
```

on maas-server

```
juju add-machine ssh:<mass user name>@<ipaddress>
```

Once the returns with “created machine n"

```
juju add-unit <service> –to n
```

At that point, they power on, deploy the service as required and work fine.

This is not my  end goal, as, while I can shut down the systems for our Christmas break, I will have to turn them on using the iLO websight.

```
2015.12.18 Edit number 2-----------------------
```

OK.  Stumped.

They did not respond to manual MAAS power on commands after having been commissioned (and actually booting and commissioning) multiple times from MAAS.

After being acquired, deployed and provisioned and run for a few days, they now power off and on under manual command in MAAS.

Anyone have an idea how to mark this?  I don't think it is answered, but it works.

I'm not looking this gift horse in the mouth, but I remain perplexed.

Comment: Anyone have an idea how to mark this? I don't think it is answered, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Off hand, I'd guess this is mostly an HP issue since the Dell stuff works fine.

I'd suggest first seeing if there are firmware updates for your hardware.  There tends to be quite a few bugs in HP's iLO IPMI implementations though usually their power interfaces seem reliable.

Second, logs are in

```
/var/log/maas
```

There's a lot of information in there for debugging.

Last, you can try some of this stuff manually.  Maas uses ipmi_chassis_config tool to boot machines.  You can try executing that directly from your machine. Docs are available in man pages or here:

http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipmi-chassis-config

See /etc/maas/templates/power/ for some of the options on this.  Also check the versions of the ipmi tools on your machine and look for bug reports on that.

Comment: It seems to work now.  While commissioning did not solve it (though they did power up commission and power down, multiple times), acquiring and deploying them in maas, and then hard adding the machines to juju and assigning them to a service did get them up and running, and maas is now able to power them on and off.  Not sure where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having other problems with HP not deploying. One of the things I can across which may help you was that the firmware of the ilo4 will not work with the latest which I think is 2.30. If you back rev it to 2.22 it might solve your issue.

Comment: I finally RAM this to ground.  When I hand rebooted the systems, I reset the ilo security on some of them, after having had mass commission them.  With no secure path to turn them on and off,make

Comment: Maas was not able to boot then, but the login still worked, so it could be deployed and users.  I went in, reset all the ilo security settings, deleted them from Maas, restarted them, recommissioned them, and now they work like they are supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in MAAS, or in the iLO driver for MAAS. The fact that this is specific to the new model of machine suggests it's not a Juju issue.

What version of MAAS are you using?

Comment: I am using MAAS version 1.8.2+bzr4041-0ubuntu1 (trusty1)